# Windows 7: How to flash display when CapsLock, NumLock or ScrollLock is pressed?

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 can be set to **beep** when any of the **CapsLock**, **NumLock** or **ScrollLock** keys is pressed. This can be done in the **Ease of Access Center** -> **Make the keyboard easier to use** section called **ToggleKeys**.

Is there a similar trick to make the display flash when any of the above keys is pressed? I am not interested in disabling these keys.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a [growl plugin](http://blog.growlforwindows.com/2009/05/system-hardware-notifications.html) that can do it, although I can't find one like what you're looking for.